# UITabBar buttons' images wrong size

Tags: ios, swift, tabs, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController`.

I added images to the bar buttons. On the ViewController the image size is fine, but on the TabBarController it looks all messed up.

Furthermore, when I fire up the app, and click the tabs - the images change size. I read online that I need to set the inset to be, for example:

```
Top: 5, Bottom: -5
```

But then the image isn't the size I want it to be, and it overlaps the text I want it to also have.

See image please.

How do I fix that? I am using Swift.

[image: My Storyboard]

Answer (score 0):

You should set images with correct size - 32x32, because UITabBarController does not fit images automatically.

For resizing images you can use something like this: https://github.com/ymedialabs/UIImageCategories/blob/master/UIImage%2BvImage.swift

Answer (score 0):

As per Apple [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/custom-icons/), Tab Bar Icon size varies for different size glyphs and for portage and landscape mode, refer the guide below and check if the icon size is matching the size given. Make sure to verify @2x and @3x image icon sizes and add them if missing the proper size.

[image: Tab bar Icon Size Chart]

Comment: Thanks for answering ! Unfortunately, I do not understand it. How can I check my image's sizes through Xcode ? What does "Verify x2 and x3" mean ? I know under Assets there's x2 and x3, I'm just not sure what verifying them means

Comment: In Asset Catalog if you select the image, in right side attribute inspector you can check the image size under image part or just right click on the image and open in finder, it will show the image size of selected image.

Comment: min 54px width &height and max 75px width and heigth should be the size for tabbar icon

Comment: Holy. One of my pictures is 1697 x 2400. Haha, that's what you get when you get pics from Google. They can't be resized using Xcode ? Any recommendations on how to resize them ?

Comment: ohh, you can use preview to resize the icon but best would be to use tools like Sketch.